PlantUML Package that contains two components of another package
I want to have one rectangle or package that includes the component K1 and K2 in a plantUML component diagra. Is this possible in plantuml with a package or some sort of rectangle?

Here is what I got with plantuml so far:
https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuIf8JCvEJ4zLK2ekICnJo2zBBLB8DbJGLyWsKbAeHiW6boRf1a0vXY2PvFpSWloyrBmIXGe598wt8LU5WguTYEQgvSAktmXLVoMoTYEkIg1s45qBX0wfUIb0Hm80

@startuml
package "span over k1 / k2" {
package "Sub-Package 1" {
component x 
component K1
x -> K1
}

package "Sub-Package 2" {
component y
component K2
y -> K2
}
}
@enduml


Is it a boundary? A package would make no sense.

I understand that you want to draw a rectangle across the package to highlight a set of elements that are somehow related across the packages,  such as a layer, or some commonalities in the internal structure of the packages, or even an alternate.
So the rectangle would be a kind of alternate package or something that belongs simultaneously to several packages.  This is as far as I know not supported in UML.   You can of course add such graphical highlights in popular drawing and modelling tools, but it's not stricto sensu UML, and there is no semantic defined for it.  Since PlantUML allows to model only a small subset of UML, it is not a surprise that the tool cannot to this either.
Indeed, the user interface of graphical graphical modeling tools allows to easily specify where the rectangle should be. StarUML for example allows very easily to add a rectangle to on the top of several packages to do what you want.  But when you move the rectangle, its content stays where it was. So the elements are not really "in" the rectangle.
The particular issue with text-to-graphic tools like UML, is that you would have to specify the boundaries of the rectangle, while the position of the objects will be calculated by the tool.  This would require a complex syntax t explain what sub element of which package should be covered, and a complex rendering algorithm to decide where to automatically position all these objects.  No trace of this syntax is provided in any of the PlantUML documentation to my knowledge, so I conclude that it's not an existing feature, not to to forget that packages by themselves are already very limited in PlantUML
